# Как получить доступ к интерфейсу ICloneable в проекте типа - библиотека классов?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

Я создал проект C# типа - библиотека классов . После чего, создал в нем файл с классом и попытался унаследоваться от класса ICloneable. VisualStudio 2017 подчеркнула имя ICloneable, указав на то что есть ошибка. В предложенных VisualStudio решениях данной проблемы предлагается самому создать данный интерфейс.

Другими словами интерфейс ICloneable недоступен/не создан.

В документации говорится что данный класс доступен по умолчанию в пространстве имен - using System; Но по факту для проекта типа - библиотека классов, это правило не работает. Поскольку пространство имен "System" подключено к моему файлу.

Ради интереса, я создал консольный проект и попытался в нем унаследоваться от интерфейса ICloneable. В итоге, в данном типе проекта интерфейс был доступен и все прекрасно работало. Выходит что вся загвоздка в типе созданного проекта.

Как получить доступ к интерфейсу ICloneable в проекте типа - библиотека классов?

Мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UrlBuilder.Url.Sections.ProductModels.Transport.Cars
{
    public class Class1 : ICloneable
    {
        public Class1 Clone()
        {
            return new Class1();
        }
    }
}
```

Как видите в VisualStudio 2017 этот код вызывает ошибку:
[image]

Comment: Какой фреймворк выбран в качестве целевого?

Comment: @PashaPash Мной был выбран заданный по умолчанию - .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: @PashaPash Я понял в чем проблема. В проекте типа - библиотека классов ( UWP ), данный интерфейс либо не предоставляется, либо, может быть, он находится в другом пространстве имен. Для проверки я создал библиотеки классов Standart, Core и Framework в них он есть и все работает как надо.

Comment: UWP - это Core, но, скорее всего версии < 2.0, а в Core интерфейс появился в 2.0

Comment: Напишите тогда ответ, коллеги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В проектах UWP интерфейс `ICloneable` [появился с поддержкой .NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/25/uwp-net-standard-2-0-preview/), начиная с версии Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0, Build 16299).

Для того, чтобы ICloneable появился - указать Min Version 16299, или при создании нового проекта, или в свойствах для уже существующего.